# Why NDSolve cannot solve such a simple set of differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a set of ODE like below, but Mathematica outputs nothing for this which greatly confused me. WHY?

```
NDSolveValue[{X''[t] + Y[t] X[t] == 0, Y'[t] == 0, X[0] == {0, 1, 2}, 
              X'[0] == {2, 3, 4}, Y[0] == {2, 2, 2}}, X, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: `Y'[t] == 0` and `Y[0] == {2, 2, 2}` are contradictory. Does `Y[t]` return a vector or a scalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your system corrected, but I believe it isn't exactly what you had in mind:

```
s = NDSolveValue[{X''[t] + Y[t] X[t] == 0, Y'[t] == {1, 1, 1}, 
                  X[0] == {0, 1, 2}, X'[0] == {2, 3, 4}, Y[0] == {2, 2, 2}}, 
                  {X, Y}, {t, 0, 10}]
ParametricPlot3D[Through@s[t], {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or perhaps:

```
s = NDSolveValue[{X''[t] + Y[t] X[t] == 0, Y'[t] == 1, 
                 X[0] == {0, 1, 2}, X'[0] == {2, 3, 4}, Y[0] == 2}, {X, Y},
                 {t, 0,  10}]
ParametricPlot3D[First@Through@s[t], {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, it's indeed `Y'[t]==0` is contradictory with the initial condition `Y[0]=={2,2,2}`, altering into `Y'[t]=={0,0,0}` is just OK! What I want is to return a vector form solution of `X[t]` so it's solved my problem. However, what still confused me is that if a vector solution is desired, why `Y'[t]=={0,0,0}` is required while `X''[t] + Y[t] X[t] == {0,0,0}` is not?

Comment: @Fred Vector ODEs were introduced in v9 and the syntax isn't  very intuitive. As a matter of fact, you should try until it works :(